# How to get a stack-trace after halt instruction in windbg without using the GUI?

Tags: windows, windbg

Typically I insert an `assert(0);` in my C++ code, start up Windbg, press F5, enter `k` and I get a stack-trace. Then I have to copy-paste it via the mouse and exit.

But I want to automate this. Is there any way I can retrieve the stacktrace and write it to a text file without having to manually use the GUI?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you can write the output from the gui to a text file using `.logopen` like so

```
.logopen c:\dump\myLog.txt
```

this will dump everything to this location, call `.logclose` to close the log so in a single line:

```
.logopen c:\dump\myLog.txt; k; .logclose
```

Secondly if you really don't want to use the gui, there is the command line version of windbg, cdb. You can execute this with some commands like so:

```
cdb -log c:\data\myLog.txt -lines -pn myApp.exe -c ".symfix;.reload;k;qd"
```

This will turn on line numbers for call stacks, output to the log, attach to your process using the name and then execture the command in double quotes which fixes the symbol server for MS, reloads, dump the call stack and quits and detaches.

Comment: `-pn` expects an existing process, but how do I make cdb run a new process? I need the equivalent of `windbg myapp.exe arg1 arg2`.
Edit: Ah I just need to pass them after the arguments.

Comment: Well this almost works except `cdb` doesn't seem to load symbols from the executable so the stacktrace isn't usable. windbg doesn't have this problem.

Comment: how about using `-i c:\myApp` or `-y c:\myApp\mySymbol` as a parameter to cdb? see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/ff539058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more info

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're not trying to debug it any further and are just trying to get a stack trace then just call this function and write the output to a file.

CaptureStackBackTrace (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204633(VS.85).aspx?ppud=4)